# Recover Visual C# 2010 Project

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, visual-studio-2010

I have spent a lot of time writing a project in Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express. While creating it I used multiple computers and opted to store the files on a external hard drive. While **finishing** my project, the hard drive crashed. I am using Windows 7.

I now have roughly one tenth of my work remaining when I open the project.

Anybody have any ideas of how I get any of it back?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/329403/how-to-recover-data-from-a-hard-drive-crash

Answer (score 2):

Good news and bad news:

Good news: from a live ubuntu CD run scalpel http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-recover-deleted-filesdata-in-ubuntu-linux/

Bad News: you might just end up with garbage.

It is important that you avoid writing anything to disk before running the recovery.

Answer (score 1):

Has the harddrive physically crashed? Or did the files get deleted, corrupted or overwritten?  If the drive is still physically working then you could try this free tool to attempt to recover the files:  http://www.piriform.com/recuva   or jump straight to their download page: http://www.piriform.com/recuva/download/standard   I have had good results with this software.  I don't work for them. :)